# knex broken after upgrading from Node.js v12 to Node.js v16.4.0

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, node-modules, knex.js

I'm experiencing below error after upgrading to Node.js v16.4.0 (from Node.js v12).

I'm using [knex](https://www.npmjs.com/package/knex) to connect to db (postgres) and using ORM - [objection.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/objection).

`KnexTimeoutError: Knex: Timeout acquiring a connection. The pool is probably full. Are you missing a .transacting(trx) call?`

Please help to resolve!

```js
import Knex from "knex";

const getConnection = () => {
    try {
        return Knex({
            client: 'pg',
            connection: {
                user: 'user',
                password: 'password',
                host: 'dbhost',
                port: 5432,
                database: 'dbname',
            },
            pool: {
                min: 0,
                max: 10,
                idleTimeoutMillis: 10000,
                acquireTimeoutMillis: 30000,
            },
            acquireConnectionTimeout: 2000,
        });
    }
    catch (err) {
        throw err;
    }
}

const getTransaction = () => {
    const con = getConnection();
    const trx = con.transaction();
    return trx;    
}
```

Comment: There is not enough information to be able to say where it comes from. Probably transactions you are creating transactions that are never closed.

Comment: having the same issue

Comment: Same issue here on plain fresh projet with only a sample query (see below).
Tried several workaround, including pooling configuration and pg settings for connection limit set to -1 or 100.

`db
  .raw('select 1')
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Connected to database - OK')
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('Failed to connect to database with ${connection}: ${err}')
    process.exit(1)
  })`
Using Node14 (also tried 16, 17), Knex 0.95.13, PG 8.7.1

Answer (score 1):

Having had the same issue, I traced the problem to an old version of the "pg" package.

Doing

> npm i pg@latest

fixed it